# Building ROS navigation from source

Tags: localization, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to use parts of the navigation package on my robot. I need to make some changes to the existing local planner and hence would like to build the package from source. I am quite new to this and was wondering if there are any instructions to do that? I am using ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have all my config files, launch files setup as instructed in the ros tutorial. I have mapping and localization set up as well. I have downloaded the whole package from the github repository and used catkin_make to build it successfully. Now should I follow the same steps as the ros tutorial to launch move base or are there any additional steps required?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315160/building-ros-navigation-from-source/) by [Manu14](https://answers.ros.org/users/39869/manu14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `catkin_make` was successful, then all you need to do is source your `catkin_ws` via
`$ . ~/path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

See [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/?answer=252502#post-id-252502) for general instructions on how to build a ROS package from source.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-02-08**:
A couple of important steps from the answer that @josephcoombe linked to are

```
$ rosdep update
$ rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
```

to make sure that you have all of the dependencies installed *before* you try to compile.

**Comment by [Manu14](https://answers.ros.org/users/39869/manu14/) on 2019-02-26**:
Thank you! Those tips helped a lot!